# Средства для сбора информации о работе приложения

Tags: java, android

Какие существуют методы для сбора информации о функционировании приложения: где произошел сбой, в какой ошибкой приложение упало и т.д.
Интересует способ, который может работать не только на приложениях, которые уже в  `Play Mаrket`, но и на тех, которые еще в процессе разработки.

Comment: Flurry, если залить на гугл в качестве альфа- бета-, то там есть Google Cloud Test, может быть как-то Google Analytics(не помню как пишется)